# How do I calculate a 16 and 32 bit checksum in C?

Tags: c, binary, hex, checksum

I'm trying to calculate the checksum of any given message, using either an 8, 16 or 32 bit checksum size. 8 bit was easy, but the method I used for 8 bit doesn't work for 16 and 32. I'm not sure if I have to create an array of integers for the binary and then add those up or modify my existing code, or do something else.

```
checksum = 0;
if (checksumSize == 8) {
    for (int i = 0; i < characterCount; i++) {
        int c = (int)message[i];
        checksum += c; 
    }     
}
```

This is what I did for the 8 bit. The checksum gets printed in hex later in the code, and the message is already padded for 16 and 32 bit checksums.

Comment: Well how to "calculate  ... checksum" really depends on the type of checksum. Do you want a CRC16 or CRC32 sum? Some other method? There are many algorithms, and which one to select depends on your use-case and requirements. What is the sum supposed to be used for? What are your requirements? What are your limitations? Your use-case?

Comment: _"but the method I used for 8 bit doesn't work for 16 and 32"_. Show your code instead of describing it and show a [mcve] including test data along with expected and actuel results.

Comment: Note that if `checksum` is a signed integer, your code risks undefined behavior should `checksum` overflow as signed integer overflow is undefined behavior.

Comment: In what manner is that an 8-bit checksum? `int` is never 8 bit.  You should use `uint8_t`. Moreover the question is completely ambiguous - is this a 16 or 32 bit sum of 8 bit values, or a sum of values of the same width as the checksum?  And if the latter, what is the byte order?  I rather suggest that your 8 bit solution does not in fact work.  You mention printing it - I suspect you are printing the least significant 8 bits, so it just _appears_ to work.  It would have been simpler to just post that code than to describe it.  Telling us about code that you don't show serves no purpose.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.